# Power BI/Query: Include value from cell in the result of if statement

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm fairly new to Power BI and Power Query. I have a table that has three separate date fields that I need to compare against each other. I wrote the following custom column which works but I'm trying to get it to include the dates in the value that is returned and I can't figure out how I need to reference the date. I wouldn't be surprised if there's a more elegant way to do the comparison but this is what I came up with. The issue I'm having is on line 2 of the code. With the way I have it right now I just get "Attachment Date Mismatch. Event Date: [Event Date] Attachment Date: [Attachment Date]". I would appreciate any help getting this working if it is possible. I would also appreciate if someone could tell me what the part inside the quotations is called. I attempted to find an answer to this but I'm not sure if it should be called a value, string or something else.

```
if [Event Date] = [Date Last Updated] and [Date Last Updated] = [Attachment Date] then "Dates Match" else
if [Event Date] = [Date Last Updated] and [Date Last Updated] <> [Attachment Date] then "Attachment Date Mismatch. Event Date: [Event Date] Attachment Date: [Attachment Date]" else
if [Event Date] = [Attachment Date] and [Attachment Date] <> [Date Last Updated] then "Upload Date Mismatch" else
if [Attachment Date] = [Date Last Updated] and [Date Last Updated] <> [Event Date] then "Event Date Mismatch" else 
if [Event Date] <> [Attachment Date] and [Attachment Date] <> [Date Last Updated] then "Dates Mismatch" else null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a seemingly long formulae, you can also use `let...in` to shorten them like this

```
let
    e = [Event Date]
    f = [Date Last Updated]
    g = [Attachment Date]
in 
    if e = f and f = g then "Dates Match" else
    if e = f then "Attachment Date Mismatch. Event Date: " & Date.ToText(e, "M/d/yyyy") & " Attachment Date: " & Date.ToText(g,"M/d/yyyy") else
    if e = g then "Upload Date Mismatch" else
    if f = g then "Event Date Mismatch" else 
    "Dates Mismatch"
```

M language does not automatically convert mismatching data-types so that they become matching, so a you cannot contatenate dates with text strings, therefore `Date.ToText` is required.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include information so as to be able to reproduce your problem, so I cannot be complete, but in general, you need to exclude your variables from being within your quotation marks.

Those clauses where you want to include the dates should look something like (assuming your various Date columns are Date.Type and not Text.Type):

```
... "Attachment Date Mismatch. Event Date: " & Date.ToText([Event Date],"desired_format") & " Attachment Date: " & Date.ToText([Attachment Date],"desired_format") ...
```

Links to the format codes are found in the MS Help article for `Date.ToText`.  An example might be `"dd-MM-yyyy"` but there are many others.